# MongoDB Querying: Order & Export Results

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have this MongoDB group-by query which works great from the Mongo console:

```
db.accounts.group(
   { cond: { "created_at" : { $gte: ISODate("2012-08-12T00:00:00Z") }}
   , key: {member_id: true}
   , initial: {count: 0, failed: 0, succeeded: 0}
   , reduce: function(doc, out) { 
        out.count++; 
        if (!doc.success)
            out.failed++
        else
            out.succeeded++
    }
   });
```

**My three questions:**

- Is there an easier way of generating this timestamp: ISODate("2012-08-12T00:00:00Z")? Can I use a date function to generate this timestamp? If so, how?
- How can I sort (asc/desc) the returned results by the grouped fields: "failed" or "succeeded"?
- Finally, how would I export the output to a flat file?

**Update**

For #3, I was basically looking for this:

```
mongo my_db --eval 'some_var=X;' --quiet my_script.js >> output.txt
```

Where my_db is the database I'm using, some_var is a variable I'm passing to my_script.js which contains my group-by query. output.txt is obviously where the output is written.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use the JS `Date` object( http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp ) which does support this date notation however the way you have done it is normally the best way to make dates, ISO dates are always better thats why Mongo changed from the normal `Date` object to these in about v1.6 or 8 (can't remember now `:\`).
2. Since group returns a single BSON document (which means results cannot be greater than 16meg) you would have to sort them client side. Correction: You cannot sort the incoming query since it is a single object as I just realised. So this is a client side thing. Though you could do that if you were using MR (I reckon).
3. Just write the returned structure to a flat file. It is a single document, I have no idea how you wish to format the results into the flat file or what language you wish to process it in however normally you would fire the group command from, say, (for example) PHP and work on it there. It is easier in these sorts of languages.

Note: Group() does not work with sharding also the aggregation framework ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/ ) will pretty much replace this I think.

Comment: Note: I'm performing these operations via client-side. So I'm looking for how to do #2 and #3 from command-line, if possible. Of course I could write a script to do everything I want, but I'm looking to see if there is a way to do it directly from the CLI.

Comment: @doremi For #3 I do not believe the JS engine (spidermonkey) has a write file module to it, the closest I found was https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/File_object which is non-standard so it's probably not there.

Comment: @doremi for #2 how would be looking to sort? I could prolly build a quicksort function in JS (or steal one) you could use but it depends on how you wish to sort.

Comment: I'd just like the results sorted by the 'failed' or 'succeeded' count in asc or desc order.

Comment: @doremi Ok to me it seems like each doc has a `failed` and `succeeded` field. As such this should be as easy to just sort, as you say, ASC and DESC on those keys, does this link help? http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort.shtml